# Is there any way to get the time stamps of samples for the response times

Tags: jmeter

When I looked at the Results table I can see the Date and Timestamp of the sampler when thy made a request to the server,but what I am looking for the timestamp of the response times of the sampler I.e the moment response got back successfully,Is there any way to get that into the Results table or Aggregate Report?

My 2d question is: Right now in the Results Table if the same script is run for multi users or multi iterations in the Thread name column it says as ThreadGroup 1-1 .For ex Threadgroup defined as 1 user Loop count is 2 or vice versa so I would like to see User-1,User 2-1under the Thread Name column instead of Threadgroupname 1-1. How can I do that?

Please advise me!

Thanks,
Raj

Answer (score 1):

Answer for 1st question:
Jmeter provides aggregate report option in the listener,adding it in your thread group will solve your problem definately
[image]
Even you can add aggregate graph which provides response time in graphical format
[image]

Answer for 2nd question:
Rename your thread group as User
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Aggregate/Summary Report Listener -> Configuration (that's a button, on the right, above the table) -> there are couple of time parameters there, including timestamp

PS As for the second - just do a replacement in the results file in whatever tool capable of doing regex search & replacement (like, Notepad++ on Win).